# My Problem in my Thesis

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Good day!
Does anyone have any idea on how to evaluate this integral?
$$
\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u} f(x,y)dxdy
$$
I only know some of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but how would I evaluate the derivative of this with respect to $u$ when it is a double integral with $u$ as the upper limits. I would appreciate your responses. I hope you can help me to work this out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's always good to show some of your own work when asking a question on MSE, to demonstrate to other users engagement in your own problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule check 2nd equation. The rule for derivative of integral with parameter. Also for others, I think integrals with parameters are not included in all engineering studies, so it is not so trivial for everybody. I mean, we didn't even mention them in calculus 1.

Comment: So far what I did is I let $F$ be a function such that $\frac{d}{du}F=f$. So
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{u} f(x,y)dxdy&=\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}F(x,y)\bigl|_{0}^{u}dy\\
&=\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}[F(u,y)-F(0,y)]dy.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then after this I apply the fundamental theorem of calculus
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}&=\frac{d}{du}\int_{0}^{u}[F(u,y)-F(0,y)]dy\\
&=F(u,u)-F(0,u).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Am I in the correct direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
Define $F:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $F(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x}\left(\int_{c}^{y}f(u,v)dv\right)du$.
Note that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$
exist and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)=\int_{c}^{y}f(x,v)dv$,
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x}f(u,y)du$. Clearly,
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$
are continuous. Finally, if $a=c$ and $b=d$, we may define $G:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $G(t)=F(t,t)$. Then, by chain rule,
\begin{eqnarray*}
G'(t) & = & F_{x}(t,t)\cdot1+F_{y}(t,t)\cdot1\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{t}f(t,v)dv+\int_{a}^{t}f(u,t)du.
\end{eqnarray*}

---

Justification: Since $f$ is continuous, $F$ is well-defined and
the order of integration can be interchanged (Fubini Theorem). Fix
$(x_{0},y_{0})\in[a,b]\times[c,d].$ Let $\phi(u)=\int_{c}^{y_{0}}f(u,v)dv.$
Observe that $\phi$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. For, since $f$ is
continuous on the compact set $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, $f$ is uniformly
continuous (Cantor Theorem). Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose
$\delta>0$ such that $|f(u,v)-f(u',v')|<\varepsilon$ whenever $(u-u')^{2}+(v-v')^{2}<\delta^{2}$.
Let $u,u'\in[a,b]$ with $|u-u'|<\delta$, then for each $v\in[c,d]$,
we have $d((u,v),(u',v))=|u-u'|<\delta$, so $|f(u,v)-f(u',v)|<\varepsilon$.
It follows that $|\phi(u)-\phi(u')|\leq\int_{c}^{y_{0}}|f(u,v)-f(u',v)|dv\leq\varepsilon(d-c)$.
This shows that $\phi$ is continuous. Now, $F(x,y_{0})=\int_{a}^{x}\phi(u)du$.
By Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_{0},y_{0})$
exists and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x_{0},y_{0}) & = & \phi(x_{0})\\
 & = & \int_{c}^{y_{0}}f(x_{0},v)dv.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly, by writing $F(x,y)=\int_{c}^{y}\left(\int_{a}^{x}f(u,v)du\right)dv$,
we can prove that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_{0},y_{0})=\int_{a}^{x_{0}}f(u,y_{0})du.$

Comment: Who gave me -1 ?? Did I make any mistake in my solution?

Comment: I have not proved that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ are continuous. However, the proof is not difficult and is left to you.